# Unable to set Signing certificate in XCode. Executable contains an invalid signature

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode9

I want to run my cordova iOS Application on my iOS Device for testing.
Following are my build settings:

[image: Build Settings]

Clicking Enable Development Signing sets the Team to None.

My build is successful. On installing, XCode shows the following error:

[image: Installation Failed]

Does it require a developer account to run the Cordova iOS build on a device for testing? The Cordova Android version is already on Play Store.

How to set a Signing Certificate without a developer account? How to fix the invalid signature error. I haven't set any signature yet.

I am completely new to iOS.

Comment: You need developer/ enterprise account for creating dev certificate. If you have dev certificate and your device added to the dev profile, only u can run it on the ios device.

Comment: Refer doc for App signing : https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have a developer account to get a signing certificate. The signing certificate pairs with your provisioning profile, which also requires a developer account to create. You need both to run on a physical device. Your device must also be registered with your account and included in your provisioning profile device list to be allowed to run the app, outside of the App Store environment.

Xcode handles much of this for you automatically, if you have a developer account set up under Xcode Preferences > Accounts > Apple IDs. On the right-hand side of that screen you have a list of "Teams" along with buttons that say "Download Manual Profiles" and "Manage Certificates..." Is anything listed in there?

Your screenshot shows a Team with your name, which *should* mean that you have a developer account already?

You also have a button in your screenshot that says "Enable Development Signing." Have you tried running that? Does it not take care of things automatically for you? "Automatically manage signing" enabled should be helping you get through these issues with simple clicks of those buttons.

Otherwise, you will need to go to the Developer portal and register a signing certificate manually. That's a process that many have written blogs and manuals about already. I don't think it is necessary to re-write what has been said by many others already. Here's a YouTube video that does a nice job of explaining things: https://youtu.be/OwXIJchrDdA

Comment: I don't have a developer account. And as I'd mentioned, clicking on Enable Development Signing changes the Team to None. Can't i simply run an iOS app on my phone to test? Without a developer account?

Comment: You need a developer account but the free account for your Apple ID should be sufficient. How are you installing this? With the device plugged in, you should be able to just Run directly on the device. An error with a simple “Fix It” might pop up. You need to make sure the Team is set to you as “Personal Team” (apologies, I’m answering from my phone, without Xcode in front of me)

Comment: Thanks. In the build settings I'd set the Any iOS SDK to "don't code sign". Setting it to iOS Developer did the trick.

Comment: Aha, gotcha. Yeah, code signing must be enabled, as you’ve discovered.